# How to inspect precompiled minified SASS code

Tags: css, sass, codekit

I'm using [Codekit](https://incident57.com/codekit/index.html) to minify all my CSS via Sass. This works great but causes an issue when inspecting the code as everything appears on line 1! I use the lines as a quick way to find the code I'm looking for.

[image]

I use the Codekit plugin for Coda, which means every time I make a change to a .scss file and save, it just auto compiles the code.

I guess everyone will tell me not to compile the code until launch, in an ideal world that's great but there will **ALWAYS** be a need to inspect the code without once it's all been compiled.

Is there a way around this? Or is this a downside of compiled code? What processes do people go through to get to the minified code? How can I tell which .scss the change is in?

I could set it to be less compressed so it's not all on one line but I would then lose the benefits of compressing it.

These are the settings I have Codekit set to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codekit supports [Source Maps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors), which will let Google Chrome show you the **original code** even after minification.

In your compilation settings, check the **Create a source map** box for SASS.

For more information, check out this [Team Treehouse article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) *(the article deals with JavaScript, but the same principle applies to CSS too)* and the [Codekit SASS documentation](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#sass).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I thought there was something that would solve the problem, seemed too big of a hole in the process otherwise!